# How to add static and dynamic Events together to fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, fullcalendar

> This is a fullcalendar which get events dynamically and I want to add 2 static events but I don't know how to add is there someone who can help me with it.I am not able to add dynamic events inside array

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
                    var str;
                    function ini_events(ele) {
                        ele.each(function () {
                            var eventObject = {
                                title: $.trim($(this).text())
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'))
                    var date = new Date()
                    var d = date.getDate(),
                        m = date.getMonth(),
                        y = date.getFullYear()
                    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');  
                    var d1 = 1;                        
                            InitializeCalendar();
                        function InitializeCalendar() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                url: "Demo.aspx/GetCalendarData",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                                        headerToolbar: {
                                            left: 'prev,next today',
                                            center: 'title',
                                            right: ''
                                        },
                                        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                                        events: 
                                            $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                                                var eventStartDate = new Date(parseInt(item.slotStartTime.substr(6)));
                                                var eventEndDate = new Date(parseInt(item.slotEndTime.substr(6)));

                                                var event = new Object();
                                                event.id = item.slotID;
                                                //event.start = new Date(eventStartDate.getFullYear(), eventStartDate.getMonth(), eventStartDate.getDate(), eventStartDate.getHours(), 0, 0, 0);
                                                //event.end = new Date(eventEndDate.getFullYear(), eventEndDate.getMonth(), eventEndDate.getDate(), eventEndDate.getHours() + 1, 0, 0, 0);
                                                event.start = eventStartDate;
                                                event.title = item.slotStatus;
                                                event.backgroundColor = item.color;
                                                event.allDay= true;
                                                return event;
                                            })
                                        }
                                    });                        
                                    calendar.render();
                                },
                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                }
                            });
                        }})
```

> the above code has jquery map function and i anm not able to put it inside events array

Comment: If you're using fullCalendar 5 you can set static events separately via https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialEvents